# Wordpress website can be acces outside LAN, but no internally UBUNTU SERVER

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, server

So I have a problem and I do not really think it has anything to do with the apache2 settings.

I have installed a wordpress website on my local server computer.
Now, I can acces phpmyadmin and anything BUT the wordpress websites.
This ofcourse makes me think its WORDPRESS and not the webservers fault.
Permalinks in wordpress are set to www.mydomain.com

Im trying to load the website from: 192.168... Localhost and my external IP. but it just sits there loading.
And when I try to acces the website from my phone/outside the local networks, the website works completely fine!

I have been working on the website for a while now and I can't really do a re-install.
Anyone know what could cause this problem?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you typed in the browser's address bar when you were trying to access the website both locally and from outside of Lan.

Comment: Hi, so locally I use either my server ip: 192.168.x.x or http://localhost
Externally I use my external IP or my subdomain.
Externally(from work/phone) it works great my internally from local(home network, it does not work.